# Read Lzo file in PySpark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark. I have a bunch of LZO indexed files in a folder. The indexing was done as indicated on https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo.

The files are as follows:

```
1.lzo
1.lzo.index
2.lzo
2.lzo.index

and so on
```

I want to read these files. I am using newAPIHadoopFile().

As given on, https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo

I did the following:

```
val files = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, classOf[com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text])
val lzoRDD = files.map(_._2.toString)
```

It worked fine in Scala (spark-shell).

But, I want to use pyspark (python-spark application). I am doing the following:

```
files = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path,"com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat","org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable","org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")
lzoRDD = files.map(_._2.toString)
```

I get the following error: AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute '_2'

The whole code is as follows:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Create the SparkContext
     conf = (SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("abc").set("spark.executor.memory", "10g").set("spark.cores.max",10))

     sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

     path='/x/y/z/*.lzo'
     files = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path,"com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat","org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable","org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")
     lzoRDD = files.map(_._2.toString)

     #stop the SparkContext
     sc.stop()
```

And I am submitting using spark-submit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: This is your exact code? I mean PySpark part.

Comment: I have added the whole code

Comment: Try something like `files.map(lambda x: x[1])`.

Comment: It is no longer giving me any error. But, can you explain the difference between the two? and why this one works? Thank You

Comment: `_._2` is just a mix of Scala syntactic sugar and the way you access tuple elements in Scala and it is simply an anonymous function. It is not meaningful in Python. `_` is sometimes used in Python to mark output as ignored. At some point it has been used with RDD. Dot syntax is used to access methods or attributes. Hence the error.

Comment: To summarize `_._2` in Scala is a function and is often used instead of something like `(t: Tuple2[T, V]) => t._2`. In Python it is an attempt to access `_.2` attribute of `_` variable and most of the time is completely meaningless.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to add "hadoo-lzo" from maven repo? Thanks

Comment: Is there way of doing the same with spark sql dataframes instead of RDDs?