# How to read LZO compressed files in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, compression, virtualenv, lzo

I am using PySpark 3.1.2 with virtual environment.

I am trying to read files compressed with `lzo` but i cant find proper documentation on how to do that, i understand that for licensing issue, the `lzo` codec needs to be added manually to spark. But i dont find a step by step documentation to do that.

I already checked the question: [Read Lzo file in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680181/read-lzo-file-in-pyspark) but id did not really help me, as i would like to add the codec in spark so im able to read directory of `lzo` files same as i do with parquet and json.

Any help will be appreciated :)